# PHP: Move file from domain to subdomain

Tags: php, file, subdomain, move

I have a site on a domain, let's call it "`mydomain.com`", where people can log in.
This domain has a subdomain `sub.mydomain.com`.

When the user uploads a file on the main domain, I want to move it to the `uploads` folder on `sub.mydomain.com`.
The folder I want to move the file to has full write/read privileges.

My code that uploads te file:

```
$filename = 'background_' . $_SESSION['username'] . '.jpg';
if (is_uploaded_file($_FILES['background']['tmp_name'])) 
    {  
        move_uploaded_file($_FILES['background']['tmp_name'], 
        "/var/www/vhosts/mydomain.com/subdomains/sub/httpdocs/uploads/" . $filename);
    }
```

When running this code I get the following warning/error:

```
Warning: move_uploaded_file() [function.move-uploaded-file]: open_basedir restriction in effect. File(/var/www/vhosts/mydomain.com/subdomains/sub/httpdocs/uploads/background_User.jpg) is not within the allowed path(s): (/var/www/vhosts/mydomain.com/httpdocs:/tmp) in /var/www/vhosts/dezeactie.nl/httpdocs/opmaak.php  on line 152
```

Can anybody enlighten me with a solution for my problem?

One final note: I know I could do the login on the subdomain and upload the file there directly, however I would like to keep the login on the main domain for other purposes.

Thanks in advance.

Jurgen

Comment: A personal pet peeve: I hate the term *subdomain* when hosting services use it as synonym for *web site* or, more specifically, *second-class web site we allow you to have so your cheap plan looks great while we still leave market for expensive plans*. :)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Your hosting service does not allow your scripts to do stuff outside the `httpdocs` directory of each virtual host and a shared `/tmp` directory. That seriously restricts the possibilities for information exchange between sites.

Tricks I can think of:

1. Store a temporary file in the `/tmp` directory from the source site and trigger a process in the target site to fetch the file. You can use the curl functions to do so.
2. Store files in a common database. The storage does not need to be permanent if you think that will affect your site performance. Target site just needs to checke whether it has pending incoming files.
3. Add files to a queue (perhaps a special directory inside `httpdocs`) and write a command line script to push them to the target site. Run this command with cron (lets say, once every minutes).

IMHO, #2 looks feasible and reliable.

Comment: maybe it's not hosted somewhere where it's impossible to change php.ini?

Comment: Thank you for your reply, #2 indeed looks like an option I could have a look at.

Answer (score 0):

As the error message suggests, file access is limited to certain directories with the [open_basedir](http://php.net/manual/en/ini.core.php#ini.open-basedir) directive in `php.ini`.

If you have access to the server's configuration, you can change that.

Comment: Eh, yeah, an obvious possibility I had totally overlooked :)

Comment: It's unclear to me what you want me to change in open_basedir. Could you give some extra explanations? For instance when I have `/var/www/vhosts/mydomain.com/httpdocs` as the main directory and `/var/www/vhosts/mydomain.com/subdomains/sub/httpdocs` as the subdomain?

Comment: @Jurgen: i don't want you to change anything, since i couldn't care less. especially since you don't seem to put any effort into it yourself, not even trying to give a bit more useful information.

Answer (score 0):

Why not create a symlink for your subdomain then reach images via sub.domain.com url?

Answer (score 0):

Most solutions here seemed a tad excessive. I've written my own solution. Take it with a grain of salt; I don't use PHP often.

```php
// MAIN DOMAIN - index.php

/**
 * @param String $target - file name under the image you are saving
 * @param String $subdomain - target subdomain, in which, you wish to save your image
 */
function saveImage($target, $subdomain) {
    $context = stream_context_create(array('http' =>
        array(
            'method' => 'POST',
            'header' => 'Content-type: application/x-www-form-urlencoded',
            'content' => http_build_query(
                array(
                    'target' => $target,
                    'contents' => file_get_contents($_FILES['image_upload']['tmp_name'])
                )
            )
        )
    ));
    
    return file_get_contents('http://' . $subdomain . '.' . $_SERVER['HTTP_HOST'] . '/save_image.php', false, $context);
}

saveImage("test.png", "cdn");


// SUBDOMAIN - save_image.php

file_put_contents($_POST['target'], $_POST['contents']);
    
echo 'http://' . $_SERVER['HTTP_HOST'] . '/' .$target;
```

I now realize that this would allow for any user to make a post request to save an image to the subdomain; however, being that PHP is back-end, the easy alternative would be to pass a key declared in PHP. i.e.

```php
// MAIN DOMAIN - index.php

$key = "A4g8S8"; // hash this and pass it through the request body


// SUBDOMAIN - save_image.php

if ($_POST['key'] == "A4g8S8") {
    // code here
}
```